# Find out from weather data whether there was a tropical night

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, temperature, mariadb-10.1

I have a lot of weather data, where I have the temperature every hour. Now I want to find out whether there was a tropical night in the whole last month.

**Definition from tropic night**:

> "A tropical night is a night in which the lowest air temperature does not drop below **20°C** between 6pm and 6am"

To find out when a tropic night was, I have to check the temperature over 2 days (from *6pm* from *day 1* to *6am* from *day 2*). So how can I reach this in `MySLQ`?

The table looks like follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `temperature` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `temperature` double NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
    
INSERT INTO `temperature` (`id`, `location`, `temperature`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(1, 1, 19.1, '2020-07-24 18:00:02'),
(2, 1, 17.8, '2020-07-24 19:00:02'),
(3, 1, 16.4, '2020-07-24 20:00:02'),
(4, 1, 16.2, '2020-07-24 21:00:02'),
(5, 1, 16.2, '2020-07-24 22:00:02'),
(6, 1, 15.7, '2020-07-24 23:00:02'),
(7, 1, 15.4, '2020-07-25 00:00:02'),
(8, 1, 15.5, '2020-07-25 01:00:02'),
(9, 1, 15.9, '2020-07-25 02:00:02'),
(10, 1, 15.5, '2020-07-25 03:00:01'),
(11, 1, 15, '2020-07-25 04:00:02'),
(12, 1, 14.4, '2020-07-25 05:00:02'),
(13, 1, 16.5, '2020-07-25 06:00:01'),
(14, 1, 24.8, '2020-07-25 07:00:01'),
(15, 1, 26.7, '2020-07-25 08:00:02'),
(16, 1, 32.5, '2020-07-25 09:00:02'),
(17, 1, 30.3, '2020-07-25 10:00:02'),
(18, 1, 30.7, '2020-07-25 11:00:02'),
(19, 1, 29.3, '2020-07-25 12:00:02'),
(20, 1, 30.4, '2020-07-25 13:00:01'),
(21, 1, 27.8, '2020-07-25 14:00:02'),
(22, 1, 27.1, '2020-07-25 15:00:02'),
(23, 1, 28, '2020-07-25 16:00:02'),
(24, 1, 27.1, '2020-07-25 17:00:02'),
(25, 1, 27.6, '2020-07-25 18:00:01'),
(26, 1, 24.1, '2020-07-25 19:00:01'),
(27, 1, 21.7, '2020-07-25 20:00:02'),
(28, 1, 20.7, '2020-07-25 21:00:02'),
(29, 1, 20.3, '2020-07-25 22:00:02'),
(30, 1, 19.2, '2020-07-25 23:00:02'),
(31, 1, 18.8, '2020-07-26 00:00:02'),
(32, 1, 18.9, '2020-07-26 01:00:02'),
(33, 1, 18.6, '2020-07-26 02:00:02'),
(34, 1, 18.6, '2020-07-26 03:00:02'),
(35, 1, 18.7, '2020-07-26 04:00:01'),
(36, 1, 18, '2020-07-26 05:00:02'),
(37, 1, 18.3, '2020-07-26 06:00:02'),
(38, 1, 25.4, '2020-07-26 07:00:02'),
(39, 1, 26.3, '2020-07-26 08:00:02'),
(40, 1, 32.7, '2020-07-26 09:00:02'),
(41, 1, 31.2, '2020-07-26 10:00:01'),
(42, 1, 31.2, '2020-07-26 11:00:02'),
(43, 1, 29.1, '2020-07-26 12:00:02'),
(44, 1, 27.9, '2020-07-26 13:00:02'),
(45, 1, 27.2, '2020-07-26 14:00:02'),
(46, 1, 28.6, '2020-07-26 15:00:02'),
(47, 1, 28.5, '2020-07-26 16:00:02'),
(48, 1, 26.3, '2020-07-26 17:00:02'),
(49, 1, 26, '2020-07-26 18:00:02'),
(50, 1, 24.5, '2020-07-26 19:00:02'),
(51, 1, 21.2, '2020-07-26 20:00:02'),
(52, 1, 20.4, '2020-07-26 21:00:02'),
(53, 1, 19.7, '2020-07-26 22:00:02'),
(54, 1, 18.3, '2020-07-26 23:00:02'),
(55, 1, 17.9, '2020-07-27 00:00:02'),
(56, 1, 16.9, '2020-07-27 01:00:02'),
(57, 1, 16.3, '2020-07-27 02:00:01'),
(58, 1, 16, '2020-07-27 03:00:02'),
(59, 1, 15.7, '2020-07-27 04:00:02'),
(60, 1, 15.6, '2020-07-27 05:00:02'),
(61, 1, 16.2, '2020-07-27 06:00:02'),
(62, 1, 29.8, '2020-07-27 07:00:02'),
(63, 1, 32.4, '2020-07-27 08:00:02'),
(64, 1, 37.9, '2020-07-27 09:00:02'),
(65, 1, 35.1, '2020-07-27 10:00:02'),
(66, 1, 33.1, '2020-07-27 11:00:02'),
(67, 1, 34.5, '2020-07-27 12:00:02'),
(68, 1, 32, '2020-07-27 13:00:02'),
(69, 1, 29.5, '2020-07-27 14:00:02'),
(70, 1, 29.7, '2020-07-27 15:00:02'),
(71, 1, 31, '2020-07-27 16:00:01'),
(72, 1, 30.8, '2020-07-27 17:00:02'),
(73, 1, 30.4, '2020-07-27 18:00:02'),
(74, 1, 29.6, '2020-07-27 19:00:02'),
(75, 1, 26.1, '2020-07-27 20:00:01'),
(76, 1, 25.3, '2020-07-27 21:00:02'),
(77, 1, 23.7, '2020-07-27 22:00:02'),
(78, 1, 22.8, '2020-07-27 23:00:02'),
(79, 1, 23, '2020-07-28 00:00:02'),
(80, 1, 22.9, '2020-07-28 01:00:02'),
(81, 1, 22.9, '2020-07-28 02:00:01'),
(82, 1, 22.2, '2020-07-28 03:00:02'),
(83, 1, 22.3, '2020-07-28 04:00:02'),
(84, 1, 21.5, '2020-07-28 05:00:02'),
(85, 1, 22.1, '2020-07-28 06:00:02'),
(86, 1, 32.8, '2020-07-28 07:00:02'),
(87, 1, 33.4, '2020-07-28 08:00:02'),
(88, 1, 36.2, '2020-07-28 09:00:02'),
(89, 1, 37, '2020-07-28 10:00:02'),
(90, 1, 31.3, '2020-07-28 11:00:02'),
(91, 1, 34.2, '2020-07-28 12:00:01'),
(92, 1, 33.9, '2020-07-28 13:00:02'),
(93, 1, 33.3, '2020-07-28 14:00:02'),
(94, 1, 31.6, '2020-07-28 15:00:02'),
(95, 1, 32.3, '2020-07-28 16:00:02'),
(96, 1, 29.2, '2020-07-28 17:00:02'),
(97, 1, 28.5, '2020-07-28 18:00:02'),
(98, 1, 26.7, '2020-07-28 19:00:01'),
(99, 1, 24.4, '2020-07-28 20:00:01'),
(100, 1, 21.9, '2020-07-28 21:00:02'),
(101, 1, 22.9, '2020-07-28 22:00:02'),
(102, 1, 22.5, '2020-07-28 23:00:01'),
(103, 1, 21.9, '2020-07-29 00:00:02'),
(104, 1, 21.2, '2020-07-29 01:00:02'),
(105, 1, 20.5, '2020-07-29 02:00:01'),
(106, 1, 19.7, '2020-07-29 03:00:02'),
(107, 1, 19, '2020-07-29 04:00:02'),
(108, 1, 18.8, '2020-07-29 05:00:02'),
(109, 1, 19, '2020-07-29 06:00:01'),
(110, 1, 18.8, '2020-07-29 07:00:02'),
(111, 1, 18.9, '2020-07-29 08:00:02');
```

<sub>Just one night from 2020-07-27 (6pm) to 2020-07-28 (6am) was a **tropic night** in the data from my database.</sub>

To show the data from my database, I have create a [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40ad30/2).

## My desired result:

My favourite statement where, do show the *date* from **each** *tropical night* per month:

> The night from **2020-07-27** to **2020-07-28** was a tropical night with a **min temperature** from 21.5°C.

So I will as output the *both dates* where the tropical night is and the min temperature in this night.

But I don't know how can I check from each day per month at 6pm to each next day at 6am to check the temperature.

Thanks for any helpful answer!

Comment: Update your question to show us what the desired result would look like. And do not use pictures to do this.

Comment: @Strawberry I have add my desired result from the statement in the question. Thanks for this hint!

Comment: Isn't the day after a tropical night always *the next day*? Why do you need both bits of information?

Comment: You mean, that just the *second* date is important? As in my example, just *2020-07-28*? And then you would say, "on 2020-07-28 it was a tropical night" ?

Comment: You say you need *'need BOTH dates from the tropical night'*. I'm just asking why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you'd do the presentation stuff in application code, but just for fun...:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' '
                ,'The night from'
                ,DATE(timestamp)
                ,'to'
                ,DATE(timestamp+INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                ,'was a tropical night with a min temperature from'
                ,CONCAT(MIN(temperature),'°C')
                ) x 
             FROM temperature 
            WHERE TIME(timestamp) NOT BETWEEN '06:00:01' AND '17:59:59' 
            GROUP 
               BY DATE(timestamp+INTERVAL 12 HOUR) 
           HAVING MIN(temperature) >= 20;

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| x                                                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| The night from 2020-07-27 to 2020-07-28 was a tropical night with a min temperature from 21.5°C |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In more recent versions of MySQL, it's possible that strict mode needs to be disabled for this to work.

Comment: Nice approach. To find the **tropical night per month** I will add in the `where`-clause after your given `where`-clause with `AND` the period of the month as `WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2020-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 23:00:00'` for the month July.

Comment: I think you're forgetting a night at either the start or the end of the month

Comment: How do you mean? If a tropical night is from 2020-06-30 to 2020-07-01?

Comment: Yep, either that one or the one at the other end of the month. But I might be wrong

Comment: yes, you presumably want `WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2020-07-01 18:00:00' AND '2020-08-01 06:00:00'` or `WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2020-06-30 18:00:00' AND '2020-07-31 06:00:00'`, depending what you consider a month

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    location,
    date(date_sub(`timestamp`, interval 7 hour)) tropical_night,
    min(temperature) min_tempurature
from temperature
where time(`timestamp`) not between '6:00:01' and '17:59:59'
group by location, tropical_night
having min_tempurature >= 20
```

I'm not clear on how month factors into it, perhaps you need to add a where condition for that.

Comment: the month factors I can reach with `where`-clause after your given `where`-clause. But I need **BOTH** dates from the tropical night. So I then can write: `The night from 2020-07-27 to 2020-07-28 was a tropical night`.